# Provider or factory for reusable modal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using AngularJS with material. I'm in the process of creating a re-usable dialog. I tried to make it as a directive but looks like it's not possible because we've to manually call $mdDialog.show/hide methods. I'm confused whether I've to use a factory or provider in this case?

Comment: A provider is necessary only if you need to be able to configure the way the dialog service will work before the application starts. I doubt it's the case. So use factory or service. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: I would check also modals on angular-ui and reconsider use of directive with a service responsible just for show/hide.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I'm using factories.